# How to call function within a function to get price of a list?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm new to scheme and I'm trying to create a function that uses another function to get the price of a list.
I have the list:

```
(define-struct store(id desc price))
(define master (list
   (make-store 1 'milk 2.50)
   (make-store 2 'meat 3.29)
   (make-store 3 'eggs 1.99)
   (make-store 4 'cereal 2.99)
   (make-store 5 'bread 2.79)
   (make-store 6 'soda 1.29)
   (make-store 7 'water 4.99)))
```

And the funtcion that looks in that list to find elements:

```
(define (lookup lst id)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((= (store-id (car lst)) id)
         (list (store-id (car lst))
               (store-desc (car lst))
               (store-price (car lst))))
        (else (lookup (cdr lst) id))))
```

How would i go about calling this function in another function to get the price to be printed alone? Am i wrong in thinking i can't do so without modifying the lookup function? Can someone walk me through this?

Answer (score 0):

`Lookup` returns list or `#f`, so before getting price, you need to check what was returned. Don't modify your code and just add this:

```
(define (get-only-price id)
  (let ((found (lookup master id)))
    (if found (third found) #f)))

(get-only-price 3)
(get-only-price 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why go and change the way you return a list when you can just return the object:

```
(define (lookup lst id)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((= (store-id (car lst)) id) (car lst))
        (else (lookup (cdr lst) id))))
```

A `store` is actual one sales item so I'm guessing the name is slightly off. In a function you can get the price this way:

```
(define (product-price id)
  (let ((item (lookup master id)))
    (and item (store-price item))))
```

In the event the id was not to be found this will also return `#f`. If you are sure it exists (or want it to fail when it doesn't) you can just do this:

```
(store-price (lookup master id))
```